# Issues with the new popup guide for searching

Tags: discussion, bug, search, popups

[image]

I just noticed that addition.

- Searching for posts by author does not need the brackets `[]`, and can be clearer as to what "1234" is. A new user may think 1234 is a username example.
- Tag guideline can be clearer, for example: `[tag-name]`.

Comment: Also side note, the search by author guidance is wrong...

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, but as the first comment shows, discussion can help refine that guide.

Comment: we normally just add these small improvements to the canonical [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) but feel free to turn this one into a bug report to capture animusons comment.

Comment: @rene: TIL. I went to edit the FAQ now, but the guideline says a link to a meta answer/blog is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One of the new search hints is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332999/one-of-the-new-search-hints-is-wrong) Not an exact duplicate, but the answer there also takes into account issues reported here, and status-completed them.

Comment: @Luuklag: Thanks for letting me know. Closed now.

Answer (score 2):

Someone somewhere is typing `"words here"` in a search box...

Doesn't `score:3` refer to questions AND answers? Yet the guide specifically says "questions with 3+ votes".

Comment: That is bit of the problem. Searching, specially how SE implemented it is rather complex. You can't get every detail about it in that fly-out, yet you want to trigger users to try some of those options without having a *no hits*. It should invite them to  visit the advanced search instead.

Comment: @rene Oh, I fully understand the motivation behind this feature and  where the tips are supposed to nudge a user to but just substitute the word "questions" with "posts" and Bingo!

Comment: Bingo! Did we win anything?

Comment: In a sense, yes. You earn accuracy over misleadinghood (not a real word but a better one doesn't come to mind now)

Comment: I thought you needed `score:3..` to get 3 _and more_, but maybe not.

Comment: @marcellothearcane typing score:3 in the search box will pull up questions and answers that have a positive score of three upvotes or more (3+)