# One of the new search hints is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

There's a new popup helping you with searching, but one of the hints is wrong:

[image]

Searching for [`score:3`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A3) will return *answers* as well as questions, and it's not the number of (up/down)votes which counts, it's the score. Better would be "posts with a score of 3 or higher" or "questions and answers with a score of 3 or higher".

Comment: Most of these are weird and wrong. `[tags]` implies putting multiple tag names into the brackets instead of bracketing each individual tag name. You don't use brackets to perform a user search. And I don't know what "search within status" is meant to convey for isaccepted...

Comment: I use `user:me` quite often, but if I know I'm searching for a post by Shog9, I go to his profile page and then it's already prefilled. I never ever have to type that phrase.

Comment: Related: [Issues with the new popup guide for searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332998/issues-with-the-new-popup-guide-for-searching/333002#333002)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this! I missed sanity-checking those search hints before getting them out.

I just pushed a fix for the `score:3` copy and changed the `[tags]` and `[user:1234]` examples along the way.